# получить пароль от HotSpot на iPhone

Tags: ios, wifi, bluetooth, пароль, hotspot

всем привет! возник такой вопрос:
Может ли iOS Application получить данные HotSpot на телефоне, на котором оно установлено?
данные нужны все, включая пароль

Суть в том, что есть некое устройство, которое "на борту" имеет BT и WiFi модули.
Чтобы была возможность подключиться к iPhone через взведенную точку доступа, нужно получить данные сети (включая пароль)
Предполагается, что некое iOS App получает данные HotSpot и по BT передает устройству, то в свою очередь уже подключается к HotSpot и делает свои интересные штуки)

Заранее благодарю за ответы)

Answer (score 0):

Если Ваше устройство не `MFi`, то вариантов нормальных нет.

Из всего что доступно - можно получить `SSID`. Нельзя получить пароль. Нельзя получить текущий статус hotspot'a.

Можно сделать диалоговое окно, чтобы пользователь сам ввёл данные и их передать на Ваше устройство.